# Indexing a Keras Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

The output layer of my Keras functional model is a tensor `x` of dimension `(None, 1344, 2)`. I wish to extract `n < 1344` entries from within 2nd dimension of `x` and create a new tensor `y` of size `(None, n, 2)`.

It seems straight-forward to extract `n` consecutive entries by simply accessing `x[:, :n,:]`, but (seemingly) difficult if the `n` indices are non-consecutive.  Is there a clean way in Keras to do so?

Here are my approaches so far.

**Experiment 1** (Slicing a tensor, consecutive indices, works):

```
print('My tensor shape is', K.int_shape(x)) #my tensor 
(None, 1344, 2) # as printed in my code
print('Slicing first 5 entries, shape is', K.int_shape(x[:, :5, :]))
(None, 5, 2) # as printed in my code, works!
```

**Experiment 2** (Indexing tensor at arbitrary indices, fails)

```
print('My tensor shape is', K.int_shape(x)) #my tensor 
(None, 1344, 2) # as printed in my code
foo = np.array([1,2,4,5,8])
print('arbitrary indexing, shape is', K.int_shape(x[:,foo,:]))
```

Keras returns the following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 0
From merging shape 1 with other shapes. for 'strided_slice_17/stack_1' (op: 
'Pack') with input shapes: [], [5], [].
```

**Experiment 3** (Tensor flow backend function)
I have also tried `K.backend.gather` but its usage is unclear because 1) Keras documentation states that the indices should be a tensor of integers and there is no Keras equivalent of `numpy.where` if my goal is to extract entries in `x` satisfying a certain condition and 2) `K.backend.gather` appears to extract entries from `axis = 0` whereas I want to extract from the second dimension of `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [tf.gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) which will index based on an index array:

```
# From documentation
indices = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
params = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
output = ['a', 'd']
```

To use it in a Keras model make sure to wrap it in a Layer like `Lambda`.